# creating function with value from json in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, getattr

I am looking for an solution for calling functions with values from an jsonfile with variables.

What i have done so far:

```
import json

def anotherfunc(x, inputdata):
  fruitname = x["Parameters"][0]["Name"]
  print(fruitname + inputdata.decode("utf-8"))


class EncDec: 
   def __init__(self, input_file):
     pass 
     with open(input_file, "r") as intput_handle:
         self.input = json.load(intput_handle)

  def __getattr__(self, name):
      message = [x for x in self.input["FRUIT_Messages"]
               if x["Name"] == name]
      return anotherfunc(message[0], data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     file = EncDec("C:/Users/lamu7789/Documents/Python_Project/new.json")
     data = b'\x00\x00'
     x = file.berrys(data)
```

I am reading an json file in with **init**.
Afterwards I am trying to call a function with the name "berrys". It does work because **getattr** works if the Attribute "berrys" does not exists.
The Problem is, that **getattr** only takes on variable.
But i need a second variable 'data' for further uses.
Is there a solution that i am able to work with `x = file.berrys(data)` to pass the data to the `anotherfunc(x, inputdata)` ?
The only solution i found is to pass the 'data' variable with the path for the jsonfile and pass it to anotherfunc afterwards. But i would like to have the name and the data into one function call.

Thats my Json:

```
    "Name": "FRUITS",
    "Description": "Json full of fruits",
    "FRUIT_Messages": [
      {
        "Name": "berrys",
        "Sweet": 1,
        "Description": [
          "sweet and yummy"
        ],
        "Parameters": [
          {
            "ID": 1,
            "Type": "uint8",
            "Name": "strawberry",
            "Description": [
              "Color: red",
              "Season: Summer",
              "Ground: Field"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your `__getattr__()` must not actually call the function; the top-level code is going to do that itself.  You need to return a function - but it can't be `anotherfunc` itself because you need to provide one parameter to it.  `functools.partial()` is the general solution for providing some parameters to a function without calling it yet; you could also write this as `return lambda *args: anotherfunc(message[0], *args)`.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you so much!! Thats what i wanted!!